# Devo especificar o tipo do retorno de um procedimento em Python?

Tags: python, funções, tipagem, estilo-de-codificação, return

A algum tempo tenho estudado e aprendido um pouco mais sobre o Python. Recentemente li um artigo que falava sobre a descrição da tipagem em python usando o modulo `typying`. Desde que aprendi sobre esse recurso tento melhorar o código adicionando esse recurso com o objetivo de melhorar a documentação e também a manutenção.

Alguns dias atrás, com a adição desse recurso, me deparei com uma dúvida sobre a melhor forma de se descrever um procedimento. Imaginei que pelo conhecimento que possuo até o momento a melhor forma seria a seguinte.

```py
def foo() -> None:
    pass
```

Porém conversando com um amigo, percebi que essa forma poderia não ser a melhor já que por ser um procedimento, partimos da definição que durante a execução não iremos retornar nenhum objeto, nem mesmo o objeto `None`.

Surge então a forma já conhecida:

```py
def foo():
   pass
```

que atende o objetivo desejado de se descrever o procedimento, porém continuamos sem uma descrição clara de que essa função será um procedimento, portanto, não irá retornar nada.

Mesmo conhecer um pouco mais sobre uma forma atualizada e completa em termos de descrição da função e documentação de um procedimento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python permite usar a tipagem explícita. Não quer dizer que ela se tornou uma linguagem de tipagem estática, mas ajuda deixar o código mais legível e até pegar alguns erros algumas ferramentas extras.

Cada um adota um estilo que faz mais sentido para você. Eu acho que deve ser consistente, ou adota a tipagem ou não. Nada impede de usar ambos e até pode fazer algum sentido adotar só em alguns casos bem específicos ou o oposto e deixar de adotar a tipagem só quando deseja que ela seja dinâmica mesmo, ou seja, só quando você sabe que a variável pode ter valores de mais de um tipo.

Se você usar sem critério não faz muito sentido, perde valor.

Eu vejo mais o pessoal não adotando a tipagem, o que faz sentido para *scripts*. Mas hoje muita gente usa Python como se ela não fosse uma linguagem de *script*, aí a tipagem começa ser mais importante. Então porque as pessoas gostam de usar a mesma ferramenta para tudo acaba ficando complicando estabelecer o melhor jeito.

[image: Um tipo de canivete suíço com machado, martelo, etc.]

Se você adotou a tipagem sempre que possível então eu acho que deveria ser consistente.

Python só tem funções e o procedimento é simulado retornando nada, mesmo que implicitamente.

Quando faz um procedimento, que na verdade é uma função que retorna nada, e decidiu ser explícito na tipagem, então só tem uma forma consistente de escrever esse código:

```
def foo() -> None:
    pass
```

É um erro dizer que algo que não tem um `return` explícito não retorna nem mesmo um `None`, porque retorna:

```
def foo():
   pass

print(foo())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3oxgsy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fjdomjyk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/ReturnNone.py).